# Orthogonal projection onto column space of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U$ be the column space of the matrix $A$ given by
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & -1\\
> 1 & 2\\
> 1 & -1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   Then the orthogonal projection  of $(0 \ 1 \ 0)^T$ on $U$ is?
>
> 1. $(0\ 1\ 0)^T$
> 2. $(0\ 0\ 1)^T$
> 3. $(1\ 1\ 0)^T$
> 4. $(1\ 0\ 1)^T$

P.S. Answer is 4th option and I do not understand how. Please explain.

Comment: Do you know how to find the projection of a vector on another vector? Do you know what it means to project a vector on a subspace?

Comment: A column vector is written `$\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$`.

Answer (score 1):

U=span{(1,1,1),(-1,2,1)}
Observe that (0,1,0)=(1\3)(1,1,1)+(1/3)(-1,2,-1)
Since  (0,1,0)belongs to U
So orthogonal projection of (0,1,0) on U is (0,1,0).
Hence, option 1 is correct.

Comment: Hi Akshya. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Answer (score 0):

It must be $1$, because $(0,1,0)^t\in U$.

Comment: When i solved it, answer was 1 but the correct option is 4th one. Please give me more explanation.

Comment: When you project a vector in a subspace onto that same subspace you get the same vector back.  The answer you were given must be incorrect.